# Code Sign Javascript to use 'new ActiveXObject()' / 'GetObject()'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, code-signing

I've got a javascript file that uses

```
excel = GetObject("", "Excel.Application");
```

to hook a current running instance of excel, however it requires me to drop my security settings super low. How do I go about code-signing a javascript file to at least cause a security prompt instead of just failing? Google-ing keeps getting me results for signing custom activex controls, .dlls, and .exes but all I need is the built-in function approved.

On a related note
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tf9xwsc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx
"The GetObject function is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 standards mode or later."

What is the proper method for accessing a currently running application in IE9 then?

Comment: It'll be a really great day when people stop writing Windows-dependent web applications :-)

Comment: I totally agree, however my audience here is a company that ONLY uses IE and this was the fastest route. Believe me, I tried to talk them into allowing a modern browser like Chrome/Firefox but that was a no-go

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem with Catia, we'll be switching soon from IE9, which support VBscript, to IE11, which not, so i though moving to Java, but then GetObject isn't working either. But, @Pointy, i'm interested in what you say: how would you call Excel from Firefox or Chrome? That could be a start for my investigation or an argument to switch to another browser

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that; there's no "code signing" mechanism for JavaScript.

Comment: Gotta say I doubt that's entirely true as the function is a built in javascript function of IE and IE itself wants it code-signed. I saw something about including the .js in a .cab file but I have no idea how to go about that or if that's even valid

Comment: Well I suggest you start scouring MSDN, because there's no way I've ever heard of to securely "sign" a JavaScript source file.

Comment: Yep, back to MSDN then. You're in the same boat as me lol, never heard of signing js before this either.

Comment: Actually, Firefox has support for it
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html

Comment: @stumpedcoder I can't tell what that stuff is intending to document - the word "Firefox" doesn't appear anywhere in the document, and a lot of those documents seem very old (like maybe they're about the mostly-defunct Mozilla browser and not Firefox).

Comment: oh I see - it has to do with the (Mozilla-only, as far as I can tell, though it's not something I know much about) "jar:" URL scheme.

Comment: yeah, basically it looks like they put the javascript files in a java archive (jar) along with a certificate. Rather odd saying that javascript and java are completely different languages. I'll experiment with that and see what comes of it.